# How to prove that the function $ 2^{x}$ in the Interval $[a, b] $ is Riemann integrable?

Tags: integration

The definition of Spivak's book states that a function is Riemann integrable if the upper and lower sums match,  I have only found the expressions of the upper and lower sums with the help of the Taylor series. 
Is there another easier way to do it?

Comment: What is the "integral definition of Spivak's book"? Adding this detail to your answer means more people will be able to help as they won't have to go and look it up

Comment: Do you want to show $\int 2^x$ is Riemann integrable or that $2^x$ is Riemann integrable? Anyway, perhaps noticing that $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}$ helps?

Comment: Continuous functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: I think Kevin wants to do this using the definition with upper and lower sums, not more advanced results about integration.

Comment: I can only show it using partitions, use the development Taylor of  $ 2^{x} = e^{x ln 2}$ But I'm not convinced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do $\int_0^1 2^x\;dx$ as an example.
Let $\epsilon > 0$.
We will need to know that $2^x$ is continuous at $x=0$; there is $\delta > 0$ so that $2^\delta < 1+\epsilon/2$.
Let $x_0 = 0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = 1$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ with $x_k-x_{k-1} < \delta$ for all $k$.  The function $2^x$ is increasing, so
$$
M_k := \sup_{x_{k-1} \le x \le x_k} 2^x = 2^{x_k} .
$$
So the upper sum is
$$
U = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{x_k}\;(x_k-x_{k-1}) .
$$
Similarly the lower sum is
$$
L = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{x_{k-1}}\;(x_k-x_{k-1}) .
$$
Then
\begin{align}
U - L &= \sum_{k=1}^n \big(2^{x_k} - 2^{x_{k-1}}\big)\;(x_k-x_{k-1})
\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{x_{k-1}}\big(2^{x_k-x_{k-1}}-1\big)\;(x_k-x_{k-1})
\\ &\le \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{1}\big(2^{\delta}-1\big)\;(x_k-x_{k-1})
\\ &< \sum_{k=1}^n 2\big(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\big)\;(x_k-x_{k-1})
= \epsilon \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-x_{k-1}) = \epsilon .
\end{align}

There exist upper sum $U$ and lower sum $L$ with $U-L < \epsilon$.  Therefore,
$\int_0^1 2^x dx$ exists.